# Как в с++ работать с Вариативными функциями?

Tags: c++

bool bitarray::add(bool n, ...)

Как пройти по всем элементам, передаваемых в функцию?

Comment: Так же, как и в С. Однако это вопрос к вам: как вы собираетесь передавать в функцию информацию о том, *сколько* этих аргументов? Без этого невозможно ответить на вопрос о том, где заканчиваются "все".

Comment: См. `<stdarg.h>`. [`va_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list) и соответствующие макросы. Только учтите, что вы не можете вытащить количество передаваемых параметров непосредственно из вызова...

Comment: В С++ реализовывать такие функции не стоит.

Comment: А зачем вам в С++ старые variadic functions? Возьмите шаблоны с переменным числом параметров.